# pf out interface?

Tags: freebsd, pf, nat

I'm trying to figure out how to allow all hosts in $dmz to reach any host when egressing $extif. I can't seem to find the equivalence of netfilters "-o $extif", and I'd like to avoid specifically blocking everything and allow the rest.

To illustrate, I'd like to:

```
pass in on $dmz from $dmz:network to any via $extif keep-state
```

Thus, not allowing $dmz:network -> $lan.

pf version is that of FreeBSD 9.2, by the way.